# Truncate String to target length using only whole words

Tags: java, strings

I've got a bit of code that I'm wanting to tidy up. The aim is to take a `String` that consists of multiple words connected by a separator (It's produced using `Collectors.joining(SEPARATOR)` as below, although the stream processing is not quite so trivial), and return a portion from the front of it.

This portion should *never* contain partial words, but should in most cases be less than the `TARGET_LENGTH` number of total characters. It is safe to assume that the words themselves do not contain the `SEPARATOR` character.

```
String SEPARATOR = "-";
int TARGET_LENGTH = 20;

//Expected output: "this-is-a-sample"
String s = Arrays.asList("this", "is", "a", "sample", "string")
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.joining(SEPARATOR));

if (s.length() > TARGET_LENGTH) {
    if (s.contains(SEPARATOR)) {
        if (s.substring(0, TARGET_LENGTH + 1).contains(SEPARATOR)) {
            return s.substring(0, s.substring(0, TARGET_LENGTH + 1).lastIndexOf(SEPARATOR));
        } else {
            return s.substring(0, s.indexOf(SEPARATOR));
        }
    }
}
return s;
```

Expected output is as follows:

```
s                                   ||  result
"easy"                              ||  "easy"
"simple-case"                       ||  "simple-case"
"very-long-input-will-be-truncated" ||  "very-long-input-will"
"countercountermeasures"            ||  "countercountermeasures" //Longer than 20 chars
"countercountermeasures-foo-bar-baz"||  "countercountermeasures" //Longer than 20 chars
"a-b-c-d-e-f-g-veryveryverylongword"||  "a-b-c-d-e-f-g"
```

The provided code works, but isn't very clear and I imagine it will be horrible to maintain if any requirements change in the future. I'm looking for suggestions as to how it could be improved. I've considered adding a filter to the `Stream` that generates the `String`, with a counter keeping track of the current output length declared outside of the string-generation, but this feels like an even worse thing to do (At a guess I'd have to do something silly like update the counter from within a call to `Stream.map()`)

Answer (score 4):

## Style

> ```
> if (s.length() > TARGET_LENGTH) {
>     if (s.contains(SEPARATOR)) {
>         if (s.substring(0, TARGET_LENGTH + 1).contains(SEPARATOR)) {
>             return s.substring(0, s.substring(0, TARGET_LENGTH + 1).lastIndexOf(SEPARATOR));
>         } else {
>             return s.substring(0, s.indexOf(SEPARATOR));
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

The above code is cumbersome. When you have a return statement inside an if-condition, there is no reason to have an 'else' condition.

Additionally, when you are using early-returns anyway, there's no reason to have such nested code blocks....

## Alternatives

I can see multiple options to this problem. I would recommend testing them to see which performs better for you. The Regex option may in fact be faster if the pattern is reused often.

### On the fly

In your own answer, you suggest on-the-fly building of the string, and ending early. This is a good option, but I would do it differently:

```
public static String portion(final int length, final String separator, String...words) {
    if (words.length == 0) {
        return "";
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);
    sb.append(words[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < words.length; i++) {
        if (sb.length() + separator.length() + words[i].length() > length) {
            return sb.toString();
        }
        sb.append(separator).append(words[i]);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

### Regex

Yeah, yeah, the whole "use a regular expression, now you have two problems...." but, this concept is:

1. If the String is < 20 chars, or has a separator within the 20 chars, take the longest string.
2. If the string is >= 20 or there are no separators within 20, then take until the end of string, or the first separator, whichever is shorter.

If you have the separator `-` and the length `20`, then this can be expressed in the regex:

```
^(.{0,20}(?=$|-)|.*?(?=$|-))
```

where:

```
.{0,20}(?=$|-)
```

is: find up to 20 chars followed either by the end-of-line, or a separator.

and:

```
.*?(?=$|-)
```

is: otherwise, if the previous test fails, take until the end-of-line, or the next separator, whichever happens first.

You can build this in to a reusable pattern (and being defensive about separators that may have special regex meaning....):

```
private static final Pattern buildPattern(int length, String separator) {
    String qpat = Pattern.quote(separator);
    return Pattern.compile(String.format("^(.{0,%d}(?=$|%s)|.*?(?=$|%s))", length, qpat, qpat));
}
```

Then, you can use this as follows:

```
public static String portion(Pattern pat, String s) {
    Matcher mat = pat.matcher(s);
    mat.find(); // patterns will always match, will never fail...
    return mat.group();
}
```

I imagine this can be used, in your code, like:

```
private static final Pattern TWENTY_DASH = buildPattern(TARGET_LENGTH, SEPARATOR);
```

and then in your remaining code:

```
String s = Arrays.asList("this", "is", "a", "sample", "string")
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.joining(SEPARATOR));

return portion(TWENTY_DASH, s);
```

### Return-Early

Having suggested the RegEx option, I would also suggest a simplified lastIndexOf/indexOf using early-returns, instead of nested if-blocks:

```
public static String portion(final int length, final String separator, String text) {

    if (text.length() <= length) {
        return text;
    }

    int pos = text.lastIndexOf(separator, length);
    if (pos >= 0) {
        return text.substring(0, pos);
    }

    pos = text.indexOf(separator, length);
    if (pos >= 0) {
        return text.substring(0, pos);
    }

    return text;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach that I've just considered is to write it in a style more similar to how I would have done in previous versions of Java, but using the new `java.util.StringJoiner` and a `Stream` wrapper around a single word to allow the more elegant way of applying several processing steps before adding it to the result (i.e. avoiding variable declarations for intermediate steps whilst applying processing `String lowered = word.toLowerCase(); String processed = foo(lowered);`):

```
String SEPARATOR = "-";
int TARGET_LENGTH = 20;

List<String> words = Arrays.asList("this", "is", "a", "sample", "string");

StringJoiner result = new StringJoiner(SEPARATOR);
for (String word : words) {
    if (result.length() > 0 && TARGET_LENGTH - result.length() < word.length() + 1) {
        break;
    }

    Optional<String> processedWord = Stream.of(word)
            .map(w -> w.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH))
            //Additional processing
            .findFirst();

    if (processedWord.isPresent()) {
        result.add(processedWord.get());
    }
}

return result.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using [String.indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int,%20int)) would make your life easier:

```
    String result;

    String SEPARATOR = "-";
    int TARGET_LENGTH = 20;

    int indexToCutFrom = s.indexOf(SEPARATOR, TARGET_LENGTH);
    if (indexToCutFrom >= TARGET_LENGTH)
    {
        result = s.substring(0, indexToCutFrom); 
    }
    else
    {
        indexToCutFrom = s.lastIndexOf(SEPARATOR);
        if (indexToCutFrom != -1)
        {
            result = s.substring(0, indexToCutFrom);
        }
        else
        {
            result = s;
        }
    }

    return result;
```

Comment: I don't think that would work with my third sample input (`"very-long-input-will-be-truncated"`) but I'd somehow missed that I could provide `indexOf` with a `fromIndex` parameter, which may help.

Comment: It does work, I tested it.

Comment: Sorry, yes it did work with that sample. I've added the case it doesn't seem to hit as a new sample (`"a-b-c-d-e-f-g-veryveryverylongword"`) - there are no occurrences of the separator after `TARGET_LENGTH` so `result` is never cut, but it could be cut at a `SEPARATOR` before `TARGET_LENGTH`.

Comment: You're right. I edited my answer.

Comment: If you want to be efficient you can dodge the `lastIndexOf' if the 'indexOf' returned `-1`. I'm sure that's a principle: Finite sets with no first member have no last member either and only one set has that property.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered rolling your own `Collector`? There is likely to be a more concise way compared to my suggestion below, but that's all I got for now by closely following the implementation of `Collectors.joining()`.

```
public class StringTruncateCollector implements Collector<CharSequence, StringTruncate, String> {

    private Supplier<StringTruncate> supplier;

    public StringTruncateCollector(final CharSequence delimiter, int maximumLength) {
        this.supplier = () -> new StringTruncate(delimiter, maximumLength);
    }

    @Override
    public Supplier<StringTruncate> supplier() {
        return supplier;
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<StringTruncate, CharSequence> accumulator() {
        return StringTruncate::add;
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<StringTruncate> combiner() {
        return StringTruncate::merge;
    }

    @Override
    public Function<StringTruncate, String> finisher() {
        return StringTruncate::toString;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics> characteristics() {
        return Collections.emptySet();
    }

    static final class StringTruncate {
        private StringJoiner joiner;
        private int maximumLength;
        private boolean firstAdded = false;

        public StringTruncate(final CharSequence delimiter, int maximumLength) {
            this.joiner = new StringJoiner(delimiter);
            this.maximumLength = maximumLength;
        }

        public StringTruncate add(CharSequence newElement) {
            if (acceptInput(newElement.length())) {
                joiner.add(newElement);
            }
            firstAdded = true;
            return this;
        }

        public StringTruncate merge(final StringTruncate other) {
            if (acceptInput(Objects.requireNonNull(other).length())) {
                joiner.merge(other.joiner);
            }
            firstAdded = true;
            return this;
        }

        private boolean acceptInput(int incomingLength) {
            return length() + incomingLength <= maximumLength || !firstAdded;
        }

        public int length() {
            return joiner.length();
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return joiner.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

`StringTruncate` is just a simple wrapper for a `StringJoiner` that checks for the incoming `CharSequence` length first before calling the methods on the `StringJoiner` instance. Like I said earlier, I'm not sure at the moment whether there is a more concise way of doing this or not. I also had to rely on a `firstAdded` boolean value to ensure we have at least the first word as the output.

The test for it:

```
public class StringTruncateCollectorTest {

    static final String DELIMITER = "-";
    static final int MAX_LENGTH = 20;

    static enum TestCase {
        EASY("easy", "easy"),
        SIMPLE_CASE("simple-case", "simple", "case"),
        LONG("very-long-input-will", "very", "long", "input", "will", "be", "truncated"),
        EXACT("countercountermeasures", "countercountermeasures"),
        TOO_LONG("countercountermeasures", "countercountermeasures", "foo", "bar", "baz"),
        EXTREME("a-b-c-d-e-f-g", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "veryveryverylongword");

        private String expected;
        private String[] inputs;

        TestCase(final String expected, final String... inputs) {
            this.expected = expected;
            this.inputs = inputs;
        }

        void verify() {
            assertThat(Stream.of(inputs)
                    .collect(new StringTruncateCollector(DELIMITER, MAX_LENGTH)),
                    equalTo(expected));
        }
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "test-cases")
    public Iterator<Object[]> getTestCases() {
        return Stream.of(TestCase.values()).map(current -> new Object[] { current }).iterator();
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "test-cases")
    public void testCase(final TestCase current) {
        current.verify();
    }
}
```

The usage is as follows:

```
Arrays.asList(...).stream().collect(new StringTruncateCollector(DELIMITER, MAX_LENGTH));
```

Comment: There's a small bug for `firstAdded`, see if you can find it...